# Post collection of selected values to server action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I have a form with a product-warranty list.

Each list item has checkbox.

How can I post a list of SelectecSources (warranties) to the server?

What do I have to change in that code?

The WarrantyPlusViewModel object is posted to the server. It contains a list SelectedSources which should contain the selected warranty articles.

Is it possible at all to use a complex object for the selected list?

Consider I have to post the WarrantyPlusViewModel to the server which includes

the SelectedSources property with the selected warranty objects.

```
@model WarrantyPlusViewModel

<div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">

        @using (...)
        {
            <table class="table table-striped">
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.ProductSelected.Name)</th>
                    <th>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.ProductSelected.Description,l)</th>
                    <th>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.ProductSelected.Price)</th>
                </tr>
                @foreach (var product in Model.ProductList)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="SelectedSources" value="@product" /></td>

                        <td>@product.Name</td>
                        <td>@product.Description</td>
                        <td>@product.Price</td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </table>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
            @Html.HiddenFor(p => p.SerialNumber)
        }

    </div>

[HttpPost]
public virtual async Task<ActionResult> Save(WarrantyPlusViewModel viewModel)
{ 
   return View(MVC.WarrantyPlus.WarrantyPlus.Views.OverviewWarrentyPlus, viewModel);
}

 public class WarrantyPlusViewModel
    {

        // other properties

        public List<WarrantyPlusProductViewModel> ProductList { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<WarrantyPlusProductViewModel> SelectedSources { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really hard to bind this way. If you want to do it you should [override Model Binder](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/605595/ASP-NET-MVC-Custom-Model-Binder).

If i were on your place i will just use `ProductId` with some knowlege of [list binding](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/) and come up with this solution:

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.ProductList.Count(); i++)
{
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="ProductList[" @i "].Id" value="@Model.ProductList[i].Id" /></td>

        <td>@Model.ProductList[i].Name</td>
        <td>@Model.ProductList[i].Description</td>
        <td>@Model.ProductList[i].Price</td>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: I just found this article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/706728/ASP-NET-MVC-Display-an-HTML-Table-with-Checkboxes I hope it works but reading the article quickly it seems to offer what I need, what do you think?

Comment: I have solved it with a @foreach and <input type="checkbox" name="SelectedIds" value="@p.ProductId" /> and server side viewModel:         public int[] SelectedIds { get; set; }